# museum ontology development

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology, owl, linked-data

Currently, I am involved in cultural heritage ontology development for our local museum data to serve as metadata and the upper level semantic model. Our primary goal is to move data into linked open data cloud to enrich information about the items of our museum collections.  There are several projects in this sphere already, e.g., EUROPEANA, Amsterdam Museum Linked Data, Smithsonian American Art Museum Linked Data, and so on.

If you are developing an ontology for a cultural heritage, what is the correct way to identify the existing ontoloies for items? And where to start?

Comment: What do you mean by "identify the existing ontologies"?  Once you've found them, you may want to include them in your own ontology as `owl:imports`.  If you're asking what ontologies are out there, you might get better results on [answers.semanticweb.com](http://answers.semanticweb.com/). I think that this would be a good candidate for the proposed [Semantic Web Stack Exchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53218/semantic-web), too.

Comment: That said, welcome to StackOverflow!  This question might be a bit open ended for the site, but it's an interesting question, and I look forward to seeing some answers to it, either here, or on another one of the sites I linked to.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226398416_Ontologies_for_Cultural_Heritage

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at **curate**, an ontolgy for describing museum narratives. http://decipher.open.ac.uk/curate/ontology/html

I have also used the following *extensive* list of ontologies useful, which are categorised by keyword: http://www.daml.org/ontologies/keyword.html

Answer (score 0):

you may want to read [this article](http://protege.stanford.edu/publications/ontology_development/ontology101.pdf).

Just my own experience, when start developing an ontology, the first step is to list all the related concepts, relationships, verbs, terms, or anything on a paper, keep your purpose in mind, and figure out the best way to model them.